# Display "Select" By default in Telerik drop down list MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik

I have controller action method

```
public ActionResult _SelectCustomerRole()

{

var categories =_customerService.GetAllCustomerRolesByClientId(_workContext.CurrentClient.Id, true);
 return new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name") };
}
```

I want to display "Select" Text by default in Telerik drop down..

My view is

```
 @(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                .Name("CustomerRoleNames")

                .DataBinding(bindings => bindings.Ajax().Select("_SelectCustomerRole", "Security"))
                .ClientEvents(x => x.OnChange("customerRole_OnChange"))

                )
```

Comment: Look at the overloads for SelectList

Answer (score 3):

Try (Refer [Kendo Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/index))

```
.Placeholder("-- Select --")
```

As shown below:

```
Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("AjaxComboBox").Placeholder("-- Select --")
```

**Or**

```
.OptionLabel("Select State...")
```

Working example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("stateDropdownSelect") 
        .DataTextField("Name") 
        .DataValueField("Name") 
        .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetAllStates", "Search", new { searchId = Model.SearchId })))
                                          .SelectedIndex(0)
                                          .OptionLabel("Select State...")
                                          .Events(events => events.Change(
                                              @<text>
                                                   function(e) {
                                                   multiselect_change();
                                                   }
                                               </text>
                                              ))
                                          )
```

Comment: @ SBirthare  .Placeholder("-- Select --") It displays "Select" in dropdown.. But i want it by default it should display "Select"...  and clicking on drop down it should display list of values

Comment: It should be .Placeholder("Select").SelectedIndex(0).   Anyways Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for `new SelectList` which takes a fourth parameter as the 'placeholder':

```
new SelectList(categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name", "-- Select --")
```